# Cannot load image whose URL points to github

Tags: razor-pages

I am trying to load and display images from a server.

The images are stored in GITHUB. The image paths are correct.

This has to go in a Razor page inside a @foreach loop iterating over the data from a json file, one of whose elements is the URL of the image, like

Url: imagepath

But when trying to load url('product.Image'), the url is ' ' (empty).

```
 @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    { 
        <div class="card"> 
            <div class="card-img" style="background-image: url('@product.Image');"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-text">@product.Title</h5>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    }
Here's an example  of the json:
    {
    "Id": "jenlooper-light",
    "Maker": "jenlooper",
    "img": "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/41929050/61567049-13938600-aa33-11e9-9c69-a4184bf8e524.jpeg",
    "Url": "https://www.hackster.io/agent-hawking-1/book-light-dee7e4",
    "Title": "A beautiful switch-on book light",
    "Description": "Useful stuff",
    "Ratings": null
  },
```

Everything else seems OK. Just that the image is always ' '

Comment: The JSON property is `img`, not `Image`. Please show the code that deserialises the JSON to a `Product` instance.

Comment: that was exactly the right answer. Greatly appreciated it!